Lychee frost hardiness
Can lychee tree survive temperature fall below -5°C? In my place, temperature sometimes falls even below -10 °C and I'm getting 24/7 frost for a week or longer, do you think there's a chance to overwinter in the ground?
I think I can cover young trees, will it work? It could make some basic frost protection if covered well, but, obviously there won't be any light inside.
I have 2 young lychee trees growing in pots and they are fine now, outside but winter is always the problem in such cases, what do you think?
When should I move pots inside, will my plants survive 0 °C or light frost? From what I read, they're not doing right indoors and it's not easy to overwinter them inside.

Do you feel that dry air indoors over winter is worse than freezing at -10C?

It depends if they are able to survive freezing, I guess not?

Tropical plants from Thailand way below freezing for a week?
